# An INDEX MATCH of multiple cells that I can't replicate in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm incredibly new to VBA and I have done a few basic VLOOKUPs for a project, but I now have to copy over data from 14 columns. When I use the below formula in excel it works perfectly when I drag the formula down and it ignores the blank cells.

```
=IF(INDEX(SSI!B:O, MATCH(CU11, SSI!A:A, 0), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14})="", "", 
   INDEX(SSI!B:O, MATCH(CU11, SSI!A:A, 0), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}))
```

When I try to replicate this in VBA only the first column is populated. I've played about with the ranges but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
Range("AU11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(INDEX(SSI!C[-45]:C[-32], MATCH(RC[52], SSI!C[-46], 0), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14})="""", """", INDEX(SSI!C[-45]:C[-32], MATCH(RC[52], SSI!C[-46], 0), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}))"
Range("AU11").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AU11:AU" & lr)
```

Is there a more efficient method of doing? I'm self-learning mostly by recording macros and figuring things out. Here though, I am stumped.

Comment: How are you assigning a value to `lr`? Also, you don't need to `AutoFill` here. You can assign a formula to a multi-cell range in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice to get into would be to qualify your workbook and worksheets. This will become useful if you are working with multiple workbooks. Assuming `lr` has a valid number the below should work.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub test()
        
        Dim oWB As Workbook: Set oWB = ThisWorkbook
        Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("Data")  'Change the name of the worksheet to your name
        
        oWS.Range("AU11:AU" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(INDEX(SSI!C[-45]:C[-32], MATCH(RC[52], SSI!C[-46], 0), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14})="""", """", INDEX(SSI!C[-45]:C[-32], MATCH(RC[52], SSI!C[-46], 0), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}))"
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Still very much learning so appropriate your time.